# Go update all modules

Tags: go, module, package, go-modules

Using this module as an example (using a specific commit so others will see
what I see):

```
git clone git://github.com/walles/moar
Set-Location moar
git checkout d24acdbf
```

I would like a way to tell Go to "update everything". Assume that the module
will work with the newest version of everything. Below are five ways I found to
do this, assume each is run on a clean clone. This results in a `go.mod` of 19
lines:

```
go get -u
```

This results in a `go.mod` of 14 lines:

```
go get -u
go mod tidy
```

This results in a `go.mod` of 13 lines:

```
go mod tidy
```

If I just manually delete everything in `require` and run `go mod tidy`, I get
12 lines. If I just manually delete everything in `require` and run `go get -u`, I get 11 lines. My question is, why are these methods producing different
results, and what is the "right way" to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

tl;dr;

this is what you want:

```
go get -u
go mod tidy
```

and to recursively update packages in any subdirectories:

```
go get -u ./...
```

---

The inconsistencies you are seeing is due to the inherent organic nature of software.

Using your example, commit `d24acdbf` of `git://github.com/walles/moar` most likely was checked in by the maintainer without running `go mod tidy` (explaining the longer 19 lines). If the maintainer had, then you would see the 13 line version you see at the end.

`go get -u` on it's own is more aggressive in pulling in dependencies. Also, the mere fact of updating dependencies to their latest (compatible) version, may in & of itself pull in new direct/indirect dependencies. These dependencies may grow even further if you tried this tomorrow (the latest version of some sub-dependency adds new functionality, so it needs new dependencies). So there may be a valid reason the repo maintainer fixes at a particular (non-latest) version.

[go mod tidy](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy) cleans up this aggressive dependency analysis.

P.S. It's a common misconception that dependencies will shrink after `go mod tidy`: tracking `go.sum`, in some cases this file will grow after a `tidy` (though, not in this case)

Comment: At one time `go get -u` upgraded all of the module dependencies of the modules containing the named packages, but in practice that ended up upgrading way too many irrelevant modules, so we narrowed it in Go 1.13: see golang.org/doc/go1.13#go-get.

Comment: If you are working in a module with multiple packages I´ve seen `go get -u ./...`working well

Comment: `go get -u ./...` doesn't work. It provides zero output and doesn't change anything. It's also undocumented.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan `go get -u ./...` does work. If it provides no output/changes, then there was no eligible upgrades of any dependencies. The `go` command is [documented here](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go):  see `/... at the end of the pattern can match an empty string, so that net/... matches both net and packages in its subdirectories, like net/http`

Answer (score 57):

Run `go get -u && go mod tidy` <sup>1</sup>

More details:

- [`go get -u`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-get) (same as `go get -u .`) updates the package in the current directory, hence the module that provides that package, and  its dependencies to the *newer minor or patch releases when available.* In typical projects, running this in the module root is enough, as it likely imports everything else.
- `go get -u ./...` will expand to all packages rooted in the current directory, which effectively also updates everything (all modules that provide those packages).
- Following from the above, `go get -u ./foo/...` will update everything that is rooted in `./foo`
- `go get -u all` updates everything **including test dependencies**; from [Package List and Patterns](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns)

> When using modules, `all` expands to all packages in the main module and their dependencies, including dependencies needed by tests of any of those.

`go get` will also add to the `go.mod` file the `require` directives for dependencies that were just updated.

- [`go mod tidy`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy) *makes sure go.mod matches the source code in the module*. In your project it results in 12 lines because those are the bare minimum to match the source code.
- `go mod tidy` **will prune `go.sum` and `go.mod`** by removing the unnecessary checksums and transitive dependencies (e.g. `// indirect`), that were added to by `go get -u` due to newer semver available. It may also add missing entries to `go.sum`.

---

Note that starting from Go 1.17, newly-added *indirect* dependencies in `go.mod` are [arranged in a separate `require` block.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432877/why-there-are-two-require-blocks-in-go-mod-since-go-1-17)

---

<sub>1: updates dependencies' newest minor/patch versions, `go.mod`, `go.sum`</sub>

Comment: At one time `go get -u` did upgrade all of the module dependencies of the modules containing the named packages, but in practice that ended up upgrading way too many irrelevant modules, so we narrowed it in Go 1.13: see https://golang.org/doc/go1.13#go-get.

Answer (score 27):

There are some hidden dragons, here is what I recommend:

- `go get -u ./...` walks all packages in your project. **This is the command you want to use.**
- `go get -t -u ./...` walks all packages in your project and also downloads tests files of these dependencies. Probably you don’t need that.
- `go get -u` updates in the current directory only. Useful for small single-package projects, just use the first version.
- `go get -u specific.com/package` updates just one (or more separated by space) packages (and dependencies).
- `go get -u specific.com/package@version` the same but to a specific version.
- `go get -u all` updates modules from the [build list](https://go.dev/ref/mod#glos-build-list) from `go.mod`. This is useful for listing (`go list -m -u all`) but not too useful for updates.

Answer (score 9):

This is also an option: [`go-mod-upgrade`](https://github.com/oligot/go-mod-upgrade), an interactive prompt. It highlights patches in yellow and breaking changes in red :)

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2):

**tldr**: use `go get -u -d ./...` for latest Go versions

Accepted answer as well as highly ranked answers with `go get -u` no longer work with latest go version.

According to [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37700) (1) cmd Go issue, the suggested option is to use `go get -u -d ./...`

> If you want to update the dependencies of all packages within a module, you want go get -u -d ./....

(1) - https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37700